# redux-form (6.5.0): How to clear form error (_error)?

Tags: forms, reactjs, redux, redux-form

It is easy to *set* a form error in `onSubmit` with

```
throw new SubmissionError({ _error: 'My form error message.' });
```

But how do I *remove* this error? It is not removed when re-submitting and it is not removed when changing fields values.

Can I manually remove the message somehow, e.g. from `onSubmit` when re-submitting the form or after a timeout?

Answer (score 1):

It's not super elegant, but you can do:

```
import { stopSubmit } from 'redux-form'

...

// remove all submit errors
dispatch(stopSubmit('formName', {}))
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Erik. Hope a better solution arrives.